# Convert SQL Query to Sybase query

Tags: sql-server, sybase, sap-ase

Below is the query in SQL, I want to covert it to SYBASE query. 
I am new to Sybase and couldn't find a proper help or example to convert this query.

```
INSERT INTO @ClientTree 
SELECT tmp.ID,
V.NAME,
t.c.value('(./@Id)[1]', 'varchar(32)'),
t.c.value('(./ObjReference[1]/@TargetId)[1]', 'varchar(32)')
FROM
(SELECT ID, CAST(CAST(BM.CONTENT AS VARBINARY) AS XML) AS MyContentXML  
 FROM MyData BM WHERE TYPE = 'SemClientGroupTree' AND DELETED = 1) tmp
 CROSS APPLY tmp.ContentXML.nodes('//SemClientGroup') t(c)
 INNER JOIN V_GROUPS V ON V.ID = t.c.value('(./@Id)[1]', 'varchar(50)')
```

the above query insert data into a temporary table ClientTree for SQL database, I want to run same query on SYBASE database to generate same output.

Comment: I assume you actually mean you want to convert the MSSQL query you have pasted over to Sybase and not the other way as mentioned in your question because there is no cross-apply Transact-SQL function in Sybase?

You may wish to re-write your question.

Comment: I have updated the question

Comment: You've updated the title however the question wording is still wrong in places see the first line.

There is no cross-apply function in sybase so you cannot convert it directly. You need to also consider how you're storing the data in Sybase (text/image column?) and look at the 'for xml' clause for XML formatting - http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc30020.1570/html/xmlb/CIHDCJCG.htm

I would suggest some information regarding the Sybase table structure could be useful to give you better feedback.